# Does the order of fit_params matter when using the python module lmfit?

Tags: lmfit

I currently have the following parameters to optimize `['Knn', 'Kss', 'Ktt', 'tn', 'ts', 'tt', 'FE']`

```py
# Knn
fit_params.add('Knn', value = Knn_i, min=Knn_LB, max=Knn_UB, vary=True)

# Kss
fit_params.add('Kss', value = Kss_i, min=Kss_LB, max=Kss_UB, vary=True)

# Ktt
fit_params.add('Ktt', value = Ktt_i, min=Ktt_LB, max=Ktt_UB, vary=True)

# tn
fit_params.add('tn', value = tn_i, min=tn_LB, max=tn_UB, vary=True)

# ts
fit_params.add('ts', value = ts_i, min=ts_LB, max=ts_UB, vary=True)

# tt
fit_params.add('tt', value = tt_i, min=tt_LB, max=tt_UB, vary=True)

# FE
fit_params.add('FE',  value = FE_i, min=FE_LB, max=FE_UB, vary=True)
```

Will the results differ I change the order to say something like `['tn', 'FE', 'Knn', 'tt', 'Ktt', 'ts', 'Kss']`?  Would there be any reason to believe they would not?

Inside the python debugger I can prettyPrint the class structure

```py
IPdb [1]: pprint.pprint(fit_params)
Parameters([('Knn',
             <Parameter 'Knn', value=1920120.3446234118, bounds=[1024:268435456]>),
            ('Kss',
             <Parameter 'Kss', value=71663344.41919732, bounds=[1024:268435456]>),
            ('Ktt',
             <Parameter 'Ktt', value=77146988.69681165, bounds=[1024:268435456]>),
            ('tn',
             <Parameter 'tn', value=838.7989371561512, bounds=[8:1048576]>),
            ('ts',
             <Parameter 'ts', value=976.643262263194, bounds=[8:1048576]>),
            ('tt', <Parameter 'tt', value=520.0015376886633, bounds=[8:32768]>),
            ('FE',
             <Parameter 'FE', value=1.929e-06, bounds=[9.313225746154785e-10:1]>)])
```

but it seems that the order matters.  When I look at the minute adjustments of each parameter with each iteration the first parameter "Knn" changes first, "Kss" changes second, and the last one is "FE".

Is there any way to mix up the order of a class object?  Or would the best way to be just write them in the order that I would like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters are ordered because they must map to an array (a 1D numpy array, that is) of variables.  That order matters only in the sense that it cannot change during the fit.  So, yes, one of the parameter values will be changed first (and probably consistently the first one defined, as Parameters is a subclass of an ordered dictionary).  You should be able to alter that by simply changing the order in which you add entries into the Parameters object.

But the results for any fitting problem should not depend on that order of the Parameters.